# $K$-theory exact sequence.

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-k-theory

Let $Y$ be a closed subspace of a compact space $X$. Let $i:Y \to X$ the inclusion and $r:X \to Y$ a retraction ($r \circ i = Id_Y$). I have to prove that exists this short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to  K(X,Y) \to K(X) \to K(Y)  \to 0.$$
Then I have to verify that $K(X) \simeq K(X,Y) \oplus K(Y)$. How can I do it? I think that $K(X,Y) = \tilde{K}(X/Y).$ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

This is purely formal and relies on the fact that $K$ is a contravariant functor from topological spaces to abelian groups (actually to commutative rings but this is not needed here).
Since $r\circ i=Id_Y$ we get $i^*\circ r^*=Id_{K(Y)}$ so that $r^*:K(Y)\to K(X)$ is a section of $i^*:K(X)\to K(Y)$ and your exact sequence of abelian groups $ 0 \to  K(X,Y)  \to K(X) \stackrel {i^*}{\to} K(Y)  \to 0$ splits , yielding the required isomorphism $K(X) \simeq K(X,Y) \oplus K(Y)$.

By the way, it is indeed true  that $K(X,Y) = \tilde{K}(X/Y)$ but this fact is irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: But, how can I prove that the first map is iniective?

Comment: Dear tgh90: look it up in [Atiyah's *K-Theory*](http://www.amazon.com/K-theory-Advanced-Classics-Michael-Atiyah/dp/0201407922), page 69. As Abel said: read the masters!

Comment: But my problem is not the proof of the exactness in the middle (that is always true) but the exactness at the left of this sequence $0 \to K(X,Y) \to K(X) \to K(Y) \to 0.$

Comment: Exactness on the left  is proved in Chapter II, Section 2.29, page 67 of Karoubi's [*K-Theory*](http://books.google.fr/books?id=i3A1T7nhVHMC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

For the exactness at the left, you can use the long exact sequence in $K$ theory. Then every map involving (suspensions) of $i$ will split (why). Then the long exact sequence breaks down in short exact sequences.